# Service Stops On phone lock

Tags: android, sockets, android-intent, service, android-service

I have a service running in android app that receives messages in the LAN ,My service work fine all the time when phone is on but when I lock the screen manually or it locks automatically my service don't work and receives no messages , sometimes it receives 2 to 3 messages but then it stop again.
My service is:

```
public class Server extends Service {
    static String UDP_BROADCAST = "soft.b.peopleassist";
    public static String ip;
    //Boolean shouldListenForUDPBroadcast = false;
    DatagramSocket socket;

    //Intent intent;
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")

    public String getIpAddr() {
           WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
           WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
           int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

           String ipString = String.format(
           "%d.%d.%d.%d",
           (ip & 0xff),
           (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
           (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
           (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

           return ipString;
        }





void setIP()


    {
      ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {

        ip="192.168.1.255";
        Log.i("server", "AP connected so 192");
        }
        if (!mWifi.isConnected()) {

        ip="192.168.49.255";
        Log.i("server", "AP not connected so"+ip);
        }
        }





    private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(InetAddress broadcastIP, Integer port) throws Exception {
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
        if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        //  socket.setBroadcast(true);
        }
        //socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
        Log.e("UDP", "Waiting for UDP broadcast");
        socket.receive(packet);

        String senderIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress().trim();
        String message = new String(packet.getData());

        Log.e("UDP", "Got UDB broadcast from " + senderIP + ", message: " + message);

 String str=getIpAddr().trim();
//if(!str.equals(senderIP))
//{
    broadcastIntent(senderIP, message);
    String[] arr = message.split(" ", 5);
    char messagestatus = arr[1].charAt(0);
    Log.i("UDP", String.valueOf(messagestatus));
    if(messagestatus=='s')
    {
     Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    }
    //      str=null;

//}
str=null;

        socket.close();
    }

    private void broadcastIntent(String senderIP, String message) {
    Intent  intent = new Intent(Server.UDP_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra("sender", senderIP);
        intent.putExtra("messages", message);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

    void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
        UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InetAddress broadcastIP = InetAddress.getByName(ip); //172.16.238.42 //192.168.1.255
                    Integer port = 11111;
                    while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                        listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(broadcastIP, port);
                    }
                    //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        UDPBroadcastThread.start();
    }

    private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;

    void stopListen() {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
        if(socket!=null)
        socket.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopListen();
        Log.i("UDP", "Service stoped");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        shouldRestartSocketListen = true;

        startListenForUDPBroadcast();
        Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grasp a WifiManager.WifiLock to keep the wifi connection from lost.

***COPY from official Android document:

WifiLock allows an application to keep the Wi-Fi radio awake. Normally the Wi-Fi radio may turn off when the user has not used the device in a while. Acquiring a WifiLock will keep the radio on until the lock is released. Multiple applications may hold WifiLocks, and the radio will only be allowed to turn off when no WifiLocks are held in any application.

Before using a WifiLock, consider carefully if your application requires Wi-Fi access, or could function over a mobile network, if available. A program that needs to download large files should hold a WifiLock to ensure that the download will complete, but a program whose network usage is occasional or low-bandwidth should not hold a WifiLock to avoid adversely affecting battery life.

Note that WifiLocks cannot override the user-level "Wi-Fi Enabled" setting, nor Airplane Mode. They simply keep the radio from turning off when Wi-Fi is already on but the device is idle.

Any application using a WifiLock must request the android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission in an  element of the application's manifest.